# AngularJS array not updating when using ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I am learning how to use ngRoute to split my html forms into separate views. When I add data to the main array in the index.html the array updates correctly, but when I try the same approach in the html forms that are added in through the ng-view, the array does not render correctly. I can debug and see that the array is getting the new name added, but it will not render on the html.

Index.html

```
<h1> Names </h1>

<ul ng-repeat="name in names">
    <li>{{name.fname}}</li>
</ul>

<h1>Add name in index.html</h1>
<input type="text" ng-model="name" />
<button ng-click="addName(name)">add name</button>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#/first"> First</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/second"> Second</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="container">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

Apps.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when('/first', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/first.html',
    controller: 'mainController'
})

.when('/second', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/second.html',
    controller: 'mainController'
})

});

myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$log', function($scope, $log) {
$scope.names = [{fname:'john',lname:'doe'},{fname:'jane',lname:'doe'}];

 $scope.addName = function(name){
    $scope.names.push({fname:name,lname:'no last name'});     
}
}]);
```

first and second.html are identical

```
<h1>Add name in first.html</h1>
<input type="text" ng-model="name" />
<button ng-click="addName(name)">add name</button>
```

[image]

Comment: can you post what you see in $scope.names after you push the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design.

The `$scope` is limited to the scope of the controller, which is everything that is rendered inside the `ng-view`. This means there are two collections named `names`, one on the app scope, and one on the controller scope. When you modify the `names` collection inside the controller, it only modifies this collection, not the one referenced in the root level of the app. (I am assuming that you bind `mainController` to the body tag, otherwise the addName() in index.html wouldn't work. This by itself is not a great choice, you should not put another controller instance into itself, unless you absolutely know what you are doing.)

The proper way to handle this situation is to put the `names` collection and the addName() function into a service that you inject into your controllers.

Comment: Thanks for this. While I was able to get this to work by adding $broadcast to the addName() function, I didn't realize I was a putting an instance of mainController inside of itself. I'll try your approach now, thanks.